# SSIS dynamic Excel destination not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2007, ssis-2008

I created a simple SSIS package to output an SQL table into an Excel file.
I gave the dynamic name to the Excel connection manager using the expressions and set the Delay validation to TRUE on entire package, Data Flow and Excel connection Manager.
I still get the validation error as below and when I open the Excel destination, it says, "no tables or views could be loaded".

Excel connection Manager is looking for the dynamic file which is not yet created.

> Error  1   Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.      NewVendor.dtsx  0   0
>
> Error  2   Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.      NewVendor.dtsx  0   0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "Execute SQL task" to create the Excel file via a SQL statement? e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `Errors` (
    `item` NVARCHAR(255),
    `Key Data` NVARCHAR(255),
    `Create Date` NVARCHAR(255),
    `Modified Date` NVARCHAR(255),
   `Error Code` NVARCHAR(255),
   `Error Description` NVARCHAR(255)
)
```

If so then try running this on its own first to create some initial columns.This should be preceded by a File System Task to delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the connection up non-dynamically, with an actual workbook that exists. Then once this is working, add your expression to make it dynamic.